# XNA: Using Content.Load with a subclass of Texture2D

Tags: c#, xna, subclass, texture2d

So I have a subclass of Texture2D called `ScrollingBackgroundTexture`. I'd like to use it to load a texture with `Content.Load<>`, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's the code in my subclass (as of now, it's just a constructor):

```
class ScrollingBackgroundTexture : Texture2D {
    public ScrollingBackgroundTexture(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice, int width, int height) : base(graphicsDevice, width, height) { }
}
```

And here's the code from my main class that's giving me trouble:

```
test = Content.Load<ScrollingBackgroundTexture>("near stars");
```

The error tells me that the file contains a `Texture2D`, but I'm trying to load it as a `ScrollingBackgroundTexture`.

I've also tried

```
test = (ScrollingBackgroundTexture)Content.Load<Texture2D>("near stars");
```

But that just gives me another error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. Here's why.  The size of a Texture2D is X bytes big.  The size of a ScrollingBackgroundTexture is X + Y big.  The ScrollingBackgroundTexture doesn't know how to load content that is X big becasue it is X + Y big.

What you'll need to do is create your own custom content type for ScrollingBackgroundTexture.  You can find information on how to do that at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff827626.aspx).

If I were you though, I would switch to something with a bit better design that favors [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)!  This will have the added bonus of not forcing you to mess around with the content pipeline.

Comment: Ah, that explains it! I was able to create a workaround that not only functions perfectly, but is also a bit simpler. Thank you!